# How to load json api into database using talend

Tags: etl, talend, talend-mdm

I am new in Talend.  this is my api => `http://api.dss.adapt-odisha.com/aagro?url=https://mausam.imd.gov.in/api/warnings_district_api.php`

this is created design =>

[image]

> in tXMLMap

[image]

But when i am running this i am not getting data

[image]

How can i solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your api returns a json, but tRESTClient converts it to xml by default, because of "Convert response to DOM Document" setting.
I unchecked that setting, and used tExtractJSONFields to parse the json, it's working as expected.
[image]

Here's the schema of tExtractJSONFields
[image]

Comment: Do i have to write all column names in Mapping field? or automatically it can come?

Comment: How to do mapping here?

Comment: can you please show me the how you did mapping in edit schema?

Comment: You need to add all the columns to tExtractJSONFields schema in order to see them in the mapping. I've updated my answer

Comment: I did the exact the way you did. But still not getting data on tLogRow. Can you please share me this job?

Comment: Please make sure you select the column "string" and not "body" in tExtractJSONFields "Json field" setting

Comment: for above link its working fine. but the same thing i tried on my another link http://api.dss.adapt-odisha.com/aagro?url=https://mausam.imd.gov.in/api/nowcast_district_api.php then wrong data is showing on tLogRow. Why?

Comment: Well you need to change the mapping according to your data, the json is not the same !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219809/discussion-between-aashu1807-and-ibrahim-mezouar).

Comment: I created new job and you can see my updated question's last image. Here i mentioned all keys. But getting wrong data in my database or tLogRow. Why